# How to use .sty in writting in latex?

Tags: formatting, packages

I need to write my thesis in latex for which we got `.sty` file (I didn't write it myself). I have no clue what I need to do to or need to write in `.tex` file to ''activate'' those styles.

If I understood correctly there are customized macros in `.sty` file but I don't know how are they working... Do I need to write some commands in `.tex` that are defined in `.sty` file? Or it should work if I write in `.tex` `\usepackage{UNI-LJ-FE-Diploma}` --> `UNI-LJ-FE-Diploma` is name of the `.sty`.

I use Texmaker on Linux so if you could tell me steps for this program I would be very grateful.

And if any of you know some good manual for better understanding of using `.sty` and how does it work...  would be helpful too.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If the file name of the style file is indeed `UNI-LJ-FE-Diploma.sty`, then typing `\usepackage{UNI-LJ-FE-Diploma}` after the `\documentclass` instruction and before `\begin{document}` is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 10):

A .sty file is just a regular package. Make sure it is in the same folder as your thesis and include it via `\usepackage{UNI-LJ-FE-Diploma}` in the preamble. There is in principle not more to say; if you want to better understand the style file ask the person from whom you got it. Since it seems, that you are not very experienced with latex I would say dont worry to much about it at the start. Just experiment a little with LaTeX and get used with it. Then, after you gained some experience you can always go back and deeper.